# Check for objects directly under an object

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to create a platform game with XNA. I can't figure out how to detect if an object is under the "Character" object to be able to move it down if it is not above an object.

Comment: What have you tired? The concept is called Collision Detection and Google has a wealth of information about it.

Comment: I haven't looked for collision detection, but I have looked at stackoverflow for things with the same keywords as this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you are talking about is called Collision Detection and is basically the core of any game.

One of the easiest ways to handle Collision Detection in XNA is to use Rectangle. Each one of your entities (character, item, weapon, coin, enemy) should be using a Rectangle as a hitbox. Let's study a simple example :

```
class Player
{
    public Rectangle hitBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 30);
    ...
}

class Coin
{
    public Rectangle hitBox = new Rectangle(50, 50, 5, 5);
    ...
}
```

As you can see, both the entities have a Rectangle which will be used for Collision Detection (you can use it for drawing as well, but I usually use Vector2 for that).

Now, how to check if there is a collision? That's very simple :

```
class Game
{
    Player player = new Player();
    Coin coin = new Coin();

    if (player.hitBox.Intersects(coin.hitBox))
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Of course, each time you move the player, you need to set the position of the hitbox accordingly. Let's say you move the player 5 pixels to the right, you need to move the hitbox 5 pixels to the right as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BoundingBox to detect collisions, and simple positions compare to check if it is "under" something. That's 2d, man, very simple, as paper...

If your game is in 3D, my answer is the same.